# Setting multiple values in a vector to a single value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Basically, what is the best practice for programmatically specifying fan-out in System Verilog?

```
module fanout
#(
  parameter N = 4
)
(
  input i, 
  output j [N-1:0]
);
  always @ (*) begin
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) begin
      j[k] = i;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

This allows the width of the output vector to be a parameter -- are there any issues with this? Will this synthesize okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *replication operator*.  This allows you to replicate a value a fixed number of times and concatenate them.

Example (Note you need to change the output to a packed data type `output [N-1:0] j`:

```
module fanout
#(
  parameter N = 4
) 
(
  input i, 
  output [N-1:0] j
);

  assign j = {N{i}};

endmodule
```

Runnable example on EDA playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/9vn

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `default` in an assignment pattern

```
module fanout
#(
  parameter N = 4
) 
(
  input i, 
  output  j[N]
);

  assign j = '{default:i};

endmodule
```

Comment: Are there any benefits of using `default` over the replication operator? Unfortunately `default` isn't always fully supported in synthesis tools.

Comment: Can you explain what `default` is doing here?  I haven't seen it before.

Comment: See Section *10.9.1 Array assignment patterns* in the IEEE 1800-2012 LRM